# How do use the varible outside of the function?

Tags: javascript

I have created a function to get the IP Address of the user. Then I tried to give separate AD to the user. So I use if condition and try to use the value of the function (getIP) to execute the if condition. But I am not success. The main problem is that I couldn't able to use the ip variable out side of the function. Can anybody see to help me.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  function getIP(json) {
    ip=json.ip;   //Here I got the user IP Address
  }
  getIP(json);
  var KivaHan="221.120.101.58"
  var Office="221.120.99.186"
  if( ip==KivaHan ){
    document.write("Kiva Han IP Address: " + ip);
  }else{
    document.write("Office IP Address: " + ip);
  }
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this.

```
          function getIP(json) {
            return json.ip;
          }
          var ip = getIP(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `getIP` function is *synchronous*, return the IP address from it:

```
function getIP() {
    var ip; // Don't forget to declare this

    // ...get the IP address into `ip`
    return ip;
}
```

usage

```
var ip = getIP();
if (ip) {
    // Your code uses `ip` here
} else {
    // Failed to get it, handle that here
}
```

If your `getIP` function is *asynchronous*, you have two options:

Have it accept a callback, and call the callback with the IP:

```
function getIP(callback) {
    var ip; // Don't forget to declare this

    // ...get the IP address into `ip`, maybe have it set to null on error
    callback(ip);
}
```

usage:

```
getIP(function(ip) {
    if (ip) {
        // Your code uses `ip` here
    } else {
        // Failed to get it, handle that here
    }
});
```

Or use a Promise (ES2015, but there are libs that polyfill it well enough on JavaScript engines that don't do it natively):

```
function getIP(callback) {
    var ip; // Don't forget to declare this
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // ...get the IP address into `ip`
        if (/* we got the IP */) {
            resolve(ip);
        } else {
            // it failed:
            reject();
        }
    });
}
```

usage:

```
getIP()
   .then(function(ip) {
        // Your code uses `ip` here; perhaps ip == null means failure
   })
   .catch(function() {
        // Failed to get it, handle that here
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Only place where javascript creates a new scope is function. Whenever you see function keyword, its safe to assume that a new scope will be created. The problem you are facing here is you are defining ip inside a function and trying to access it outside which is logically not possible. However, you can make a global variable and can access it anywhere in your program. But downside of it is, it will clutter your global namespace and if you are unlucky you may face issues that will be weird and hard to debug.

You can make use of IIFE (Immediately Invoked function expression) which is one of the most used design pattern in javascript.

```
(function(){

  var ip = ""; //Define ip variable here.
  function getIP(json) {
            ip=json.ip;   //Here I got the user IP Address
            }
            getIP(json);
            var KivaHan="221.120.101.58"
            var Office="221.120.99.186"
                if( ip==KivaHan ){
                    document.write("Kiva Han IP Address: " + ip);

                }

                else{

                    document.write("Office IP Address: " + ip);
                }

})();
```

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with most of the Solution but not get real output which I want. Perhaps there is problem withe the function getIP(json) and the site from where I get the function to get user IP address. I think the value of this can't run out side of the function. So I used another site to get the user IP.

Now I give the alternative solution of my demand.
In this topic I want the IP Address  of an user which I get in that function. But I could not trace out this from the function which I couldn't use more time in this page.

So I use the solution given below to fill my demand..

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip">    </script><!-- To get IP Address of the user -->
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- Here variables are decleared.. -->
  var userip;
  var KivaHan="221.120.101.58"
  var Office="221.120.99.186"

</script>
</head>
<!-- Javascript for tracking and comparing the user IP-->

<!-- Below code is for implementation-->

<div class="main-bottom">
        <div class="ad">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (userip==KivaHan){

                document.write("Welcome");
            }
            else
            {
                document.write("Coming Soon");
            }
        </script>
        </div>
        <div class="ad">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (userip==KivaHan){

                document.write("Welcome");              

            }
            else
            {
                document.write("Coming Soon");
            }
        </script>
        </div>
        <div class="ad">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (userip==KivaHan){

                document.write("Welcome");

            }
            else
            {
                document.write("Coming Soon");
            }
        </script>
        </div>

    </div>
```